# Cannot use react-router BrowserRouter, Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to add react routing to my code. So I used BrowserRouter

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className = "App">
                    <Blog/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-complete-guide",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

when I try to run code I get a compile error:

```
./node_modules/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js
SyntaxError: D:\Dev\Webpack Projects\React Udemy\blogs\node_modules\react-router-dom\modules\BrowserRouter.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (11:11):

   9 |  */
  10 | class BrowserRouter extends React.Component {
> 11 |   history = createHistory(this.props);
     |           ^
  12 | 
  13 |   render() {
  14 |     return <Router history={this.history} children={this.props.children} />;

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4yQ) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I did try to install @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties. same error.

How Can I get routing to work thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok it's my fault. I used this import

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter";
```

instead of this

```
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
```